# keyboard tracker to identify when desktop games or Paint is opened

Tags: c#, keyboard, tracking

newbie to the group here. I've been out of the programming loop long enough to be pretty rusty. Anyway, I am a middle school computer tech teacher who is having problems with students goofing off with Paint and desktop games during class. Any assistance with getting an app installed by administration is not moving, so it's time to grab the bull by the horns. I know a little C#, and am trying to find out how to identify when a student has opened up Paint or a desktop game like solitaire or pinball. This could be a good service app, maybe running every 30 seconds. I have Visual Studio 2008 Express - hopefully that can be used, cuz I know it's a watered down product. I can program the guts where the message box displays and stuff, just don't know how to start the if statement checking for the open apps.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated
TIA

Comment: A better approach might be to read up on Windows security and not allow the account that the students use to open those programs. But be aware, students can be pretty savvy. I spent much of high school thwarting barriers like this so we could play games in class :)

Comment: There are several commerical products that do exactly what you want, and it's never a good idea to circumvent administration, even if you think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx)

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("mspaint"))
{
   process.Kill();

 }
```